# Custom spinner dialog for Android

Tags: android, dialog, themes, spinner

How do I do a custom theme android spinner dialog?

Comment: See here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html.  It was the first match in a Google search for "Android Spinner Example."

Answer (score 1):

This blog has an example that probably covers your question:

http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/

---

Edit:

These blog posts has a pretty similar answer:
http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-39-create-custom-spinner-in-android/
http://stephenpengilley.blogspot.no/2013/01/android-custom-spinner-tutorial.html

The key to customizing an Android Spinner is to create a custom resource for the spinner rows, and then passing that row layout into a custom adapter. In the custom adapter, one can override the following two functions:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
    // Custom view generation       
}


@Override
public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
    // Custom view generation
}
```

To determine how the Android Spinner will look to the user.

Comment: The link is expired :(

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: This needs updating, both links have expired