# Android spinner display custom dialog

Tags: android, xamarin, spinner

I read this two links but there is no answer:
[Custom theme for spinner dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132257/custom-theme-for-spinner-dialog)
[Custom spinner dialog for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934136/custom-spinner-dialog-for-android)

I have set the property of my spinner `"spinnerMode="dialog"`.
But I want my spinner to show a custom dialog. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m I want to show a custom dialog with an Imageview, Listview a button and maybe a Searchbar... when the user clicks on the spinner. But I could not find a solution how to change the dialog that the spinner shows by default. Is it clear what I am going to do?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439100/how-to-override-onclick-on-android-spinner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vigneshearan.m said:
The solution is to override the `onTouch` method of the spinner class.
In Xamarin (C#), it looks like that:

```
            _spinnerLand.Touch += (sender, e) => {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                 builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (_activity);
                builder.SetIconAttribute (Android.Resource.Attribute.AlertDialogIcon);
                builder.SetTitle ("Test");
                builder.SetMessage("This is just a test");
                builder.SetPositiveButton (Android.Resource.String.Ok, delegate (object o, DialogClickEventArgs ea) {builder = null;});
                builder.Create();

                builder.Show();
            }
        };
```